# Has the post-completion OPT grace period of 60 days after STEM graduation been extended due to the covid-19-related economic slowdown?

Tags: usa, working, students, covid-19

https://www.uscis.gov/opt mentions the post-completion Optional Practical Training (OPT) grace period of 60 days after STEM
graduation:

> Initial post-completion OPT:
>
> - Must apply within 30 days of your DSO entering the recommendation for OPT into your SEVIS record, and
> - May apply up to 90 days before you complete your degree, but no later than 60 days after you complete your degree.

Has the post-completion OPT grace period of 60 days after graduation been extended due to the covid-19-related economic slowdown? (i.e., is there any way to get some exception to this 60-day rule after graduation and apply later than that?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The post-completion OPT grace period of 60 days after STEM graduation has not been extended due to the covid-19-related economic slowdown. You can read on https://www.uscis.gov/about-us/uscis-response-to-covid-19 the response of the USCIS to covid.